# Selecting variables by clicking

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply a simple `IF ELSE` condition to my current `vba` script by selecting  a variable from my `Treeview` panel via clicking on each node. I know how to do this by selecting as an `Inputbox` but have no idea how to select by clicking?

Comment: I'm guessing you created a Treeview in a UserForm. You could use the `NodeClick` event.

Comment: Thanks @MG92, I guess thats a right function. But any idea how to specify a random variable in NodeClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new UserForm an initialized the Treeview likes this:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oNode As Node

    With TreeView1
        Set oNode = .Nodes.Add(, , "W1", ThisWorkbook.Name)
        oNode.Expanded = True

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            .Nodes.Add "W1", tvwChild, , ws.Name
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Then when you call the Userform with `UserForm1.Show` the UserForm with the Treeview is shown.

Then you can use the event `NodeClick` to do something with the Node like this:

```vb
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

    If Node.Text = "Table1" Then
       ' Do Something
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Soheil great! If this answers your question consider marking the question as answered, by marking this answer with the tickmark next to the question! :)